# Read an Excel File from an Amazon S3 Bucket using c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to read excel file from my S3 bucket. In the Response Stream, I am getting values like "PK\u0003\u0004\n\0\0\0\0\0�N0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0docProps". Could anyone help to map the stream to a data table or convert to string. And also when I see quick watch, the Read and Write Timeout has thrown some errors.

```
    using (var _client = new AmazonS3Client(accKey, secKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
                using (var response1 = await _client.GetObjectAsync("rrrrr","mmm.xls"))
                using (var responseStream = response1.ResponseStream)
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    var title = response1.Metadata["x-amz-meta-title"];
                    var contentType = response1.Headers["Content-Type"];
                    responseBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    string line;
                    string[] columns = null;
                    // Here the reader.ReadLine receiving only null values
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        columns = line.Split(',');
                        string col1 = columns[0];                    }
                }
```

Comment: before you retrieve the file from the bucket check your code if it can read the file when local. (download it manually and then open it with your code and read it). If this works retry the download again

Comment: An Excel file isn't text, so don't treat it as text (`StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` are for text). Also, .xls and .xlsx files are binary formats: they're not CSV files. Xlsx is a zip file with a complex xml format inside. You'll want to use a proper Excel capable library to read the files.

Comment: @Llama I've tried EPPlus and SpreadsheetGear. Both are not working

Comment: WHat lib are you using to read the Excel file. When done properly with a supported lib,  you can successfully read an Excel file from an Amazon S3 bucket and pass the byte [] to the supported Lib. There is an AWS example, however - its implemented in Java and uses the Java jxl.Workbook API.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I faced and resolved using just GetObject instead of GetObjectAsync(where this causes the connection error). Then I stored the response in memory stream and stored the response in Aspose excel library work book.
mazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client();

```
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = "SampleBucket",
    Key = "Item1"
};

using (GetObjectResponse response = client.GetObject(request)
{ 
   MemoryStream memorystream=new Memorystream();
using(Stream resStream =response.ResponseStream)
{
  resStream.CopyTo(memorystream);
}
Aspose.Cells.Workbook workBook = new Aspose.Cells.Workbook(memorystream);
var workSheetNames = workBook.Worksheets.ToList();
//.... Then do all your excel read operations  that supports Aspose lib
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).